# error calling c++ from java program

Tags: java

I want to call a c++ executable from a java program. But after I call it, nothing happens. Then after I close the program, there an error window appears, which says abnormal program termination.

The code looks like this :

```
    try {
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process p = rt.exec("discretize.exe");


        } catch (Exception exc) {/*handle exception*/
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and the windows error that appears look like this :

http://dc532.4shared.com/img/8e2-xhaG/debug.PNG

Comment: you need to specify the path to your exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the answer.

The problem was the command prompt didn't show up. So after searching google, I found a tip that suggested I simply put:

> cmd /c  start

before the path of the file. So I changed my code to look like this:

> Process myProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c  start D:\A_TA\KODINGAN\TA\src\discretize.exe");

.. and voila, the command prompt shows!

Answer (score 0):

I would try doing this below as found from this site: http://www.boards.ie/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=218960

Example:

```
Process myProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("path to exe");
```

Comment: yes, i change my code a little bit.
i add the path, so my code look like this

Process myProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("D:\\A_TA\\KODINGAN COBA2\\sabtu, 24-02-2012\\TA\\src\\MLC21NT-C\\discretize.exe");

but still, it doesn't do anything. and after i close the java program, the error window still appear. 

the error was from java or from c++?

Comment: Depends, I would try compiling the C++ code, and run it first on C++ if it works then.
If it works, move to Java.
I'm looking at your code to run it and it seems fine.

Comment: but i got the executable from website, and i don't have the sources to compile. if i execute it not from java program, it works fine